# Why jQuery.animate position doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, position, css-position

I want to **.animate** css **position property** from `position : relative` to `position : absolute` with jQuery.

I have a small div inside the div container and i want to expand this div when clicking on a button to fit to the window.

HTML:

```
<div id="container"> <!-- div with position:relative -->
    <div id="content"> <!-- i want to expand this div using position:absolute to extract it from the container and to give width and height 100% -->
        <button id="full">Full</button>
        <button id="collapse">Collapse</button>        
    </div>
</div>
```

I treid with `jQuery().animate` but doesn't work and i treid with `jQuery().css` and works, but not as I want.

This what i did:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#collapse").hide();

$("#full").bind("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#content").animate({
        width: "1000px",
        height:"1000px",
        top:0,
        left:0
    }, 500).css({"overflow": "visible", "position":"absolute"});
    $("#full").hide(100);
    $("#collapse").show(100); // can i use $("#collapse").css("display","block"); ?
});

$("#collapse").bind("click", function (e) {       
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#content").animate({
        width: "400px",
        height: "300px",
    }, 500).css({"overflow": "visible", "position":"relative"});
    $("#full").show(100);
    $("#collapse").hide(100);
});
});
```

[***JsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/TJwsM/2/)

Thank you very much for any help!
Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like that? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/TJwsM/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#collapse").hide();
    var p = $('#content').position();
    $("#full").bind("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#content").animate({
            width: $(window).width(),
            height:$(window).height(),
            top: '0px',
            left: '0px'            
        }, 500);
        $("#full").hide(100);
        $("#collapse").show(100);
    });

    $("#collapse").bind("click", function (e) {       
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#content").animate({
            width: "400px",
            height: "300px",
            top: p.top+'px',
            left: p.left+'px'                        
        }, 500);
        $("#full").show(100);
        $("#collapse").hide(100);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i want to animate the position, because when i click on "Full button" the div moves to top whitout any effect and then starts animation. did you noticed?

Comment: Ah yes, let me test again whether it can animate or not.

Comment: Check my update answer and demo again, now the animation you want is working (but not the very first time), I m also not sure why. But after the first click, it is working nice, top and left animates.

Answer (score 2):

`Position` proporties themselves are not animatable.
You can change the `left`,`top` and `bottom` values to get a movment effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution to the problem you mention, a rewrite:

**http://jsfiddle.net/vj36r/**

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <button id="full">Full</button>
        <button id="collapse">Collapse</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#container {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:#EEFFEE;
}
div#content {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#FFEEEE;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#collapse").hide();
    $("#content").animate({
        top: 40,
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
        marginBottom: 10
    }, 0);
    $("#full").bind("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#content").animate({
            top: 0,
            marginLeft: 0,
            marginRight: 0,
            marginBottom: 0
        }, 500);
        $("#full").toggle();
        $("#collapse").toggle();
    });
    $("#collapse").bind("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#content").animate({
            top: 40,
            marginLeft: 10,
            marginRight: 10,
            marginBottom: 10
        }, 500);
        $("#full").toggle();
        $("#collapse").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but this is not what I want. I said that i want to expand the div inside the container using position:absolute to **extract it** from the container and to give width and height 100%. Your example animate margins only. Thank you so much for any help! :)

Comment: the visual effect of changing the display-type of the element cannot be animated. Thus, going from relative to fixed will "pop" the width and height of the element.

If you REALLY want to do it, you could get the converted absolute position/bounds of the #content, set it on the #content right after setting its position=fixed, and then animate it to the full width of the viewport.

Seems a bit much, though, when this "modal-window" effect can be achieved by other easier means. I don't know the context of the project, ofcourse...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class that changes the position of the div and use the .addClass and .removeClass method to activate that class when the element is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#collapse").hide();

$("#full").bind("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("position");
    $("#content").animate({
    width: "1000px",
    height:"1000px",
    top:0,
    left:0
    }, 500).css({"overflow": "visible", "position":"absolute"});
    $("#full").hide(100);
    $("#collapse").show(100); // can i use $("#collapse").css("display","block"); ?
});

$("#collapse").bind("click", function (e) {       
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).addRemove("position");
     $("#content").animate({
        width: "400px",
        height: "300px",
        }, 500).css({"overflow": "visible", "position":"relative"});
    $("#full").show(100);
    $("#collapse").hide(100);
});
});




  css
  .position{
      position: absolute;
   }
```